# display image at 'life' size not just full size?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am working on a site where the user enters a couple of names and it is rendered in a nice font on a template to print and trace later onto something else(paper,wood,metal,etc.).

Let's assume the template is 4" x 3" life size. Is it possible to display the image 4" x 3" on all devices? Full size is different on all devices according to resolution of said device. My end goal is to make the image traceable from the screen instead of printing.If more details are needed I will certainly provide what is needed. jquery or kineticjs...

Thanks yet again,
Todd

EDIT: Just to be clear I have a 4x3 inch image I want to be displayed so if the user measures their actual screen the image will be 4x3 inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across this problem before and I'm afraid it isn't possible - the computer itself often will not know pixel density of the screen (it'll know how many pixels the screen is, but not necessarily how big the display area is).

There are ways of working around but you've often got to shift your goals:  When I've done this with maps in the past rather than displaying a scale (1:2500 or whatever), I've displayed a bar which is a known number of pixels (and I know the real world length).

In your case, you could get the user to measure a known number of pixels on the screen, enter the real-world size, and use this as a scale factor when generating your image.

Not ideal, but I think it's the best you're going to get.

Edit: Another way of doing it (which is perhaps better than getting the user to measure and enter a size) is to allow them to resize an image to the size of a known real-world object that they're likely to have lying around (for example, a credit-card).  Once they've resized the image, you'd know the pixel density and would know what size to render your image.  This reminds me of calibrating joysticks back in the '80s though...

Comment: As much as I want it to be possible, I believe you are right. Just not in the cards right now. I will provide a scale and a way to zoom the image in until it is the correct size...like you said: "Not ideal, but I think it's the best you're going to get. "

Comment: Which in the end is a decent solution..I mean for me not to impose a perfect size. The user can 'pick' the size they want...not the size I want them to have. Not so bad...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, but there are workarounds.

---

Popular belief is right: CSS absolute measurements are useless, unless your browser deliberately violates the recommendations of the spec.

On a screen, a CSS inch is 96 pixels. Things are slightly complicated for "Retina" and zoom-based devices, but you still can't trust inches. CSS media queries also don't help. JS/DOM/etc. specs can help in some cases, but as far as I know nobody has managed to build anything that handles even most cases, much less all.

---

Details on absolute units can be found under [Resolutions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#resolution), [Overriding Image Resolutions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-resolution), and [Absolute lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) in the CSS 3 docs, and in earlier versions. But here's a summary:

In original CSS, inches were supposed to be inches and pixels were supposed to be pixels, with no fixed mapping between the two. But CSS 2.1 added the assumption that there are 96 pixels per inch, without changing the definitions. This obviously means that either pixels or inches are not real (unless you have a 96dpi screen, which most people do not).

CSS 3 specifies that each CSS device has to choose whether to "anchor" to pixels or to physical measurements. It specifically recommends that high-res devices like print media should anchor to physical measurements, while low-res devices like computer screens should anchor to pixels. And therefore "… the physical units might not match their physical measurements." (In fact, they *will* not, except on 96dpi devices.)

So, with a 112dpi laptop, each device pixel maps to one CSS pixel, meaning you get .86 CSS inches per real inch.

What about a 220dpi laptop, like a 15" Retina MacBook Pro? Well, under OS X, the user doesn't directly use a 2880x1800 screen, but instead selects one of five virtual resolutions, like 1440x900 or 1680x1050 (and under the covers, the video card is actually rendering to an even higher resolution and then downscaling to 2880x1800). So, how does that map? Well, the browser could either map the 220dpi real pixels at 2x2 to 96dpi CSS pixels, meaning you get .87 CSS inches per inch, or it could map the 128dpi virtual pixels at 1x1 to the 96dpi CSS pixels, meaning you get .75 CSS inches per inch. And you will find browsers doing both, but they're gradually all accommodating to the standard set by Safari.

What about a 326dpi mobile device, like an iPhone? Things are even *more* complicated by the fact that mobile WebKit is built around tap-to-zoom, so you're generally not viewing things in the specified sizes anyway. But the best you could get would be 4x4 device pixels per CSS pixel, meaning 1.18 CSS inches per inch.

CSS 3 [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution) that let you distinguish between, e.g., the 1:1 and 2:1 cases (as 96dpi and 192dpi), but they don't let you determine the actual mapping.

So, why does CSS have all this complicated functionality if it doesn't actually work? Well, for one thing, it *does* work for print output. (In print output, *pixels* are wrong, so inches are right.) For another, it encourages designing things based on visual angles rather than fixed sizes—you really don't *want* something that's 5" wide on your 5" iPhone and also 5" wide on your 56" TV, except in rare cases. But mainly it's for backward compatibility. As the spec says, "… too much existing content relies on the assumption of 96dpi, and breaking that assumption breaks content."

---

I won't give all the details for how you can use JS to help, but the basic idea is that you can access things like the physical dimensions of the screen the window is one, and try to compute how far you are from 96dpi. See the source to [this page](http://iruler.net) for an example. But it really doesn't work. For example, I've got a laptop with a 15" 2800x1800/1680x1050 built-in screen and a 21" 1920x1200 external screen. Recent Firefox detects the internal screen as 1680x1050 at 20.6" and the external screen as 1920x1200 at 20.6". Safari detects them both as 1920x1200 at 23.6". An older version of Firefox detects them as one screen at 3600x1200 at 20.6" (and they had to work really hard to get that wrong information out of OS X…).

There are additional workarounds you can do to detect WebKit, or older Firefox, etc., and compensate for known things that they get wrong, which may raise your success ratio from 1/6 to maybe 1/2.

Flash or Java might be able to do better… but I don't think it's worth embedding either of them on the page just to measure the screen size.

---

So, what can you do about this?

The first possibility is to use PDF instead of HTML. You may have to set the disposition to encourage it to be opened in Reader/Preview/etc. instead of inline in the browser. And this still may not work, because some users may have Reader/Preview/etc. scaled by default. And even if it always worked, there are plenty of cases where this just isn't an acceptable answer.

The best pure-web solution I've seen is something like this:

- Give the user a box to enter their actual DPI.
- Include a "help" link that pops up info on how to find/measure your DPI.
- Also offer a "calibrate" interface, where you show a picture of a ruler and let them shrink/grow it until it matches a ruler they hold up over the screen.
- For certain devices (mainly iOS/Android, but also Mac laptops with the built-in screen) there are tricks you can use to guess the actual PPI.
- For other devices, the JS tricks described above be worth trying as well.
- Otherwise, fall back to either 96 or the reported PPI value.

---

What about the future?

This problem is not exactly secret. [Pixels Per Inch Awareness and CSS Px](http://static.zealous-studios.co.uk/projects/web_tests/PPI%20tests.html) discusses it (from the POV of trying to get an exact number of pixels, rather than an exact number of inches, but the issues are obviously complementary). Meanwhile, [Introduction to CSS Media Queries](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml) is a more practical "how to" article on how to use what's actually available, without getting into why it's not what you actually want. These and many other articles point out what a pain the current design is.

This comes up regularly on the [www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) list, and the argument always goes something like this: Most of the time, when people think they want physical inches, they're wrong. Think about a browser meant to be used at a different visual distance, like a TV or an iPhone. So, even if we didn't have the backward compat issues, we'd still want something close to what we have. The only time physical inches are useful are for "life size" diagrams.

But what about when you *do* want a "life size" diagram? Well… every discussion seems to end with someone saying "If you really need that, suggest adding a 'physin' unit instead of changing the 'in' unit", followed by, "I really do need that, so I suggest adding a 'physin' unit", and then things peter out. Maybe eventually it will happen, but so far, it hasn't.